# How to set env variables in azure pipeline for spring boot

Tags: azure, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have a spring boot application and I am trying to load a different app properties depending on the profile. I tried setting `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev` to the azure-pipeline but when running the application in the kubernetes pod is says
`No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default`

This is how my azure-pipeline looks

```
variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE='dev'
```

and I have:
`application.properties`
`application-dev.properties`
`application-prod.properties`

I also tried setting a variable to the pipeline and then reading with `$(PROFILE)` but also didn't work.

any thought?